# How to lock grub2 default selection?

Tags: grub2, kernel, updates

This morning linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic was installed during a software update. On my laptop this proved to be unusable after 10 minutes. I changed to linux-image-3.5.0-24-generic and all seems fine. I have updated the default grub2 selection to the 24-generic. How can I lock the default grub selection to this value so subsequent updates don't overwrite and make themselves default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### how to lock a kernel grub entry

With a bit of command line trickery, you can get the default of grub to always be a particular grub entry no matter when a new kernel is installed or updated.

In a terminal type:

```
fgrep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This will display all your grub entries - for example

[image]

Highlight the entry you want to default to - for example 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-31' in the screen-shot.  Right click and choose `copy`

Type

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the entry

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

to

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='2>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-31-generic'
```

i.e. paste the entry you want (including the quotes) BUT PREFIX with the text *2>*

Save, then type

```
sudo update-grub
```

The text *2>* is important because this informs Grub that the entry to boot from exists in the sub-menu called "Previous Linux entries"

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tool, Grub Customizer. To download,
Open terminal and type:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer [enter]
>
> sudo apt-get update [enter]
>
> sudo apt-get install grub-customizer [enter]

Open dash and search grub customizer, and run it. Edit configuration with this tool.it's easy . Go to General Settings to edit the default, time boot etc

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I installed that and was able to edit the default entry so to the version I desired. I did NOT notice how to "lock" the default so that new kernels wouldn't overwrite and make themselves default

Answer (score 0):

I just searched and found this file:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

Command `grub-mkconfig` (or `update-grub`) uses this file for default values. Try editing line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=1`.

Comment: Thats only good until the next kernel upgrade happens.

Comment: I want to insure that on subsequent kernel updates grub2 default selection REMAINS on whatever I've modified in the grub2 menu. Or is it possible to have a dual boot config based on kernel level?

Comment: Oh, I understand. This way `Kernel3` would take `Kernel2` place and `default=1` would point to `Kernel 2`, instead of `Kernel1`. But it seems `GRUB_DEFAULT` can be set to a string. I don't have the exact answer, but I thinks it's here: [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration).